# Validate if record has changed without checking all fields

Tags: validation-rule

We'd like to restrict record edits if the record is of a certain record type and the user is not one of several security profiles. We'd like to do this without having to check each and every one of the 20 or so fields by doing something like this:

```
ischanged( LastModifiedDate )
```

As sfdcfox points out in his comment, LastModifiedDate is set when a record is committed to the database, while validation rules run before the commit, therefore this won't work.

Is there anyway to validate if a record has changed without testing the value of all the objects fields (without APEX)?

Comment: LastModifiedDate is set when a record is committed to the database, while validation rules run before the commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon contemplating my problem further, my ultimate goal is to prevent edits of a record unless the user is one of several profiles. Therefore, I don't particular care if the unauthorized user changed any fields before trying to save the record.

Here's what I ended up going with:

```
and
    (
        not(isnew()), 
        RecordType.Name = "My Type",
        $Profile.Name <> "System Administrator", 
        $Profile.Name <> "Support Manager"
    )
```

If an attempt to edit an existing record of type `My Type` is made, and the user is not one of the two specified profiles, a validation error is raised. Since I don't care which fields were changed and I'm only concerned that the record is being edited, this solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you want to lock the whole record for everyone except System Admins on certain conditions. It is only checking if that specific field has changed.

I would suggest you implement something like this:

Create a new checkbox "Record Locked"
Create a workflow that sets the checkbox to true based on your certain condition. 
Update your validation rule so it says:

`AND($Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator', Record_Locked__c = true)`

Comment: @Swisher Sweet,if the answer is useful for you, accept this so that other can find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is not to check if the record has changed, simply check the users profile and if is valid or not then through the expectation so in your case it would look something like this.

if(user.profile == "Admim" , false,true)

Now only the admin can alter the record.

Comment: You can always replace `IF(condition, true, false)` with simply `condition`, and `IF(condition, false, true)` with simply `NOT(condition)`.